# How to Toogle Multiple Font Icons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed [this](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) to create Custom Font Icons and Added the links in my Code
over there I have Created Icons form SVG and added Custom Names

In my Code I have Multiple Buttons and Multiple '

Now I am using all 3 icons like this

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <a class="btn1"><i class="ic-like"></i></a>
    <a class="btn2"><i class="ic-dislike"></i></a>
    <a class="btn3"><i class="ic-happy"></i></a>
</div>
```

Now I have 3 Icons Should Toogle in my Code

So I have Given this in my Code to Toogle icons

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("i").toggleClass("ic-like2");
    });
   $("a").click(function(){
        $("i").toggleClass("ic-dislike2");
    });
   $("a").click(function(){
        $("i").toggleClass("ic-happy2");
    });


});
</script>
```

My icon names are 'ic-like,ic-like2,ic-dislike,ic-dislike2,ic-happy,ic-unhappy2'

But Now Problem is that when I open The Page all the icons are toogled to `ic-like2`

and when I click its back to normal 'ic-like'

but I want to show 'ic-like' and on click it should toogle 'ic-like2'

can any one suggest me on this kind I cant give in button and 'a' tag here almost all other divs are using same tags in bootstrap they are many So I need to give for these 3 only without changing other If I give in Button its loading other Css in 'a' tag also its loading other css

**Update**

Now When I onclick on any of the 3 icons except these 3 the icons which are there in `<a` are switching blank

can any one suggest me how to turn this off

Comment: Whats wrong with down voters I am in a big issue So shared my code.. Please dont down vote without answer or Comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can so something like this. You need to use jquery `find` selector function for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("a.btn1").click(function() {   
               $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-thumbs-o-up fa-thumbs-o-down");
      
             });
            
             $("a.btn2").click(function(){    
                 
                  $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-smile-o fa-frown-o"); 
            }); 
        
            $("a.btn3").click(function(){ 
        
               
                $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-unlock fa-unlock-alt"); 
            }); 
     });
```

```css
.fa {
 font-size: 58px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <a class="btn1"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></a>
    <a class="btn2"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></a>
    <a class="btn3"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you need jquery library

Comment: can you suggest me

Comment: Put this in your head. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have already given `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` butt its not working

Comment: yes I have used your updated code but still not working and I am using already that library

Comment: Just give me 2 min

Comment: Put console log after a click.

Comment: I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26236265/5010291) and I have added in console ..but before click only its loading.. and all icons are switching to second icon(dislike dark)

Comment: I make you demo for you.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Now its working fine.. Please Upvote My qUESTION

Answer (score 1):

Hi this might help full to you

```
    $(".btn1 > i").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("ic-like2 ic-like");
    });
   $(".btn2 > i").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("ic-dislike2 ic-dislike");
    });
   $(".btn3 > i").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("ic-happy2 ic-happy");
    });
```